# Typescript: How to correctly type this recursive function?

Tags: typescript

How to correctly type this function in typescript (parameters + return-value)?

```js
function deepValue(keys, obj) {
  const key = keys.shift();
  if (key === undefined || !(key in obj)) return undefined;
  const value = obj[key];
  if (keys.length > 0 && typeof value === 'object') return deepValue(keys, value);
  return value;
}
```

Usage-Example:

```js
const animals = {
   mammals: {
       apes: {
           count: 5
       }
   }
}

const keys = 'animals.mammals.apes.count'.split('.')
const count = deepValue(keys, animals);

// Result: count = 5
```

Comment: What do you mean "type this function"? `keys: Array<string>`, `obj: { [key: string]: any }` and return type is inferred automatically. What else do you need?

Comment: @msrumon with your annotations the return type would be `any`...

Comment: If your usage example involves `'mammals.apes.count'.split('.')` (no `"animals"`, right?!) then you just have `string[]` there and the compiler has no idea what actual keys might be in there. What type do you expect `count` to be? If it's `number` then you need to abandon `split` here in favor of e.g., `const keys = ["mammals", "apes", "count"] as const` so the compiler knows the literal keys and their order.  If that's okay then you can do it [like this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WJ1xgm) shows. Shall I write that up as an answer or am I missing something about the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will need a type that will represent the nested keys in the object:

```
type DeepKeys<T> = T extends object
  ? { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? K | DeepKeys<T[K]> : K }[keyof T]
  : never;
```

Then you must add `as const` to your `animals` object and to the `keys` array so that TS can infer the types correctly:

```
const animals = {
  mammals: {
    apes: {
      count: 5,
    },
  },
} as const;
// 'mammals' | 'apes' | 'count'
type AnimalDeepKeys = DeepKeys<typeof animals>;

const keys = ['mammals', 'apes', 'count'] as const;
// alternatively you could cast the result of split but this is unsafe
const keys = 'mammals.apes.count'.split('.') as DeepKeys<typeof animals>[];
```

Then type the function as:

```
function deepValue<T>(keys: DeepKeys<T>[], obj: T): T[keyof T] | undefined {
  const key = keys.shift();
  if (key === undefined || !(key in obj)) return undefined;
  const value = obj[key];
  if (keys.length > 0 && typeof value === 'object') {
    return deepValue(keys, value);
  }

  return value;
}
```

Call the function:

```
const count = deepValue(keys, animals); // compiles!
```

Comment: beautiful solution! I really like how you modeled the the recursive keys. very impressive @skapicic

Comment: Are you sure it compiles? I tried it in a playground and it hang for a while before erroring in 4 places. The return type is also wrong: it's `{ readonly apes: { readonly count: 5 } } | undefined` instead of `5`. The type checking on the input is a good start (although the input should be `readonly` if you use `as const`), but any combination of keys will pass the check, and the auto-completion is also a little off. If you need to type check the keys you could walk through your object along the path and fail at the first incorrect path item and return a union of the correct possible path items

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to type a recursive function is to wrap a concrete implementation in a generic facade which asserts the return type:

```js
import { Get } from 'type-lenses';

function deepValue<
    const Keys extends readonly string[],
    Obj extends Record<string, unknown>
>(keys: Keys, obj: Obj) {
    return deepValueImpl(keys, obj) as (
        string[] extends Keys
        ? unknown
        : Get<Keys, Obj> extends infer R
        ? [R] extends [never] ? undefined : R
        : never
    );
}

function deepValueImpl(keys: readonly string[], obj: Record<string, unknown>) {
    const key = keys.slice().shift();
    if (key === undefined || !(key in obj)) return undefined;
    const value = obj[key];
    if (keys.length > 0 && typeof value === 'object' && value !== null)
        return deepValueImpl(keys, value as Record<string, unknown>);
    return value;
}
```

It is used like so

```js
const count = deepValue(['mammals', 'apes','count'], animals); // number
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-2JqHFTKCrgp7l9euwBql0poLhgqrgVwADHAAGSZuCkcgQWNB3rik2EZlRGCELM5ovyW0m2hcKhUeovOCujqiQk9EmDQ3nQPBuATJ5smJxGCOFxcnY8nLo6Yd4S11A6rEcNj++DSWigWT6CUC3VwEDSECnqilJrHmbSchXo-wp-qHgwMoAVhe69U6-X7C3agQK+oZdESvT5K4hCnue+6EEkhB3kwcGEC+tCVoyO57peC5sAA9Lh8IAHobEAA)

As stated by `jcalz` in the comments, for the inference to work you need the type-level representation of the keys to be `['mammals', 'apes','count']` (and, in practice, a `readonly` version of that). It can be achieved with `as const`. I used [a const modifier](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51865) on the type parameter `Keys`.

I also changed a few minor things in the implementation:

You were mutating your input, so I added a `slice()` call. It's not the best way to handle it but I'm not going to rewrite your function.

Another thing that I had to do was to cast `value as Record<string, unknown>`. This is because `value` is narrowed as `object` in your conditional. Originally I had defined `obj` as `object` to avoid that, but that wasn't ideal because the only way to index `obj[key]` was then to cast `key as keyof typeof obj`, which  produces `never` and makes for a weird concrete return type (even if we discard it later, having `never` values is not great). Now `deepValueImpl` returns `unknown`, which is correct. Bottom line is: assertions are unavoidable.

Concerning the outer, generic, part:

I used a conditional type `as string[] extends Keys ? unknown : ...` to handle the case where `keys` is dynamic and thus just a `string[]`. In that case the return value can be anything.

`Get<Keys, Obj>` relies on a library. I guess explaining how to follow the path at the type level is a little out of scope for this answer but feel free to ask.

`Get` returns `never` when the path doesn't lead anywhere so we use a conditional type to test if we have a value, and if we don't we return `undefined`.

---

For completeness I am adding type checking and auto-completion on the input to show how it can be done without ruining type inference:

```js
import { Get, Audit, Successful } from 'type-lenses'

function deepValue<
    const Keys extends readonly string[] & Check,
    Obj extends Record<string, unknown>,
    Check = string[] extends Keys ? unknown : Audit<Keys, Obj>
>(keys: Keys, obj: Obj) {
    return deepValueImpl(keys, obj) as (
        string[] extends Keys ? unknown
        : Successful<Check> extends true ? Get<Keys, Obj>
        : undefined
    );
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgcQKYwDRwIIFcAmwmcAyrgMbmoDO1AZrgDZwC+cdUEIcA5DAJ5hUAWkaoAdtRo8AsACh5DceRjAI4uPlSowANQCGjXKgA88uBbjl11eAGlU-anFQAPGBPzOoqffnWM-HC2UMDiAOYA2gC6cABkcADCABao5ADWGOaWAPIARgBWLu6ezgBKadD4JiFh4Vi44uniEADu4gB8WXKWSakZcAC8wTChETHFHuJecA5OcAD8cI3NbRoAXDgERCZz1Fj5BR3yHQAU6Y7Um3tYEIWbhwCUiNkWPjC4UBpaOgZGqABJcCMc6XW6FZ76ZynV69EZjKKxNxTGZ7RbLJotdqw3qbMiUGj0JgmFJpdIdSalOCjYzotAwXZguCHY49OEWTaNLR0MKofCwx4AbnkLHkikaKjU320ekMxiBYBBFycmx8fgCQVq42i4IKmwq1ig1S19Qxq3aHUenMxaxebIs1kk8GVQzgyuoADpqIxgFRTo8vclgHQYP7hfa4MG4KCgoM4xjubz8HAAD4puAAQhjkY0dwKj2e70+Gi5qB54j54d6jtscAAbnLUK685FldEq5YozHPWIIjBknAKQAGeIJARCCB0euNobxnh5tIwHij6f-TPx8RMRiPHGWItfTQyv7y4HdrANtdQuAGqo1UZ1Bo2i1C2H7jQX4zh0UKOQ1+D6cRQEMZxhgQV4QH0EAIMYK47XZOB9CEWCwIjeDrEaGBNgAVl3VgsFwtIg3wcR9E2FD4OrCAMM2AAWXDv0sb9v3kP8rCo8R4GGH5ZX+U5Ih4CCoOAngsB4RDpFE9COJ4HUEMA6DqBfOQAHplLhAA9BYgA)

So we're using this 3rd type parameter `Check` so that `Keys` can reference itself in a type constraint. The intersection with `readonly string[]` is necessary to let `Audit` know it's working with a well-formed query.

The idea here again is to allow a dynamic `string[]` to be passed (not sure what the point of this function is if it's not dynamic to be honest), `Check` will return `unknown` in this case so that the intersection with `readonly string[]` is transparent.

I won't re-implement `Audit` for this answer but the idea is that we are walking down the Path, similarly to the way `Get` does it, or the way jcalz implemented `DeepValue` in his comment. If we can successfully walk the path, we return something transparent (same strategy as before), but at the first error we backtrack to the latest correct path item, work out what should be the next item (likely a union of possible items) and return a concatenation of the correct part of the path with our suggestion. If the path continues after the error, we leave the tuple open with a transparent rest expression, otherwise we close it.

Lastly, to add a little flair I do this `Successful<Check> extends true` check to return `undefined` when the check is not successful (otherwise, `Get` would use the suggestion returned by `Check`, since it intersects `Keys`). This is not strictly necessary because it should not matter what the return type is if the expression fails type checking.